# Azure Data Factory copy nested JSON to SQL table

Tags: json, sql-server, azure-data-factory

Does anyone have an easy way to convert nested JSON to a flat SQL table?  Just want to repeat the higher level data on each of the lower level detail.  It looks like it can be done in mapping, I have tried as per the MS documentation but got a table full of NULL. Here is what I have tried and the result.
[json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8e2i.png)

Option 1
Result:  Only returns the first record of the ‘assignedLicences’
[Option1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlGI3.png)

Option 2:
Returns multiple ‘assignedLicenses’ for each user, but only returns the first user id in each page.
[Option2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie7dJ.png)

Option3: as per the MS documentation
Result: returns all NULL values
[Option3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35Y9g.png)

Comment: What are the "numerous things" that you tried?

Comment: Tried using the advanced mapping to assign different levels, I think there is a solution in there somewhere but cannot get it.  Any suggestions you have I am happy to try, I'm getting nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try:

1.click `import schemas` button

2.if you have a JsonArray,select it.

3.you can directly see and edit the fields' JSON paths by opening `Advanced editor` .

[image: mapping]

Here is a Microsoft documentation about it.Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#tabularhierarchical-source-to-hierarchical-sink).

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks Steve, gave it a go exactly as per the MS documentation but end up with a table full of NULL.  My closest example is using a similar collection reference, but I only get the first record for each page of data.  Wondering if I need to look at my paging?

Comment: Can you provide a sample like your json file?

Comment: Hi Steve, I added an image to the original post.  Will that do?  I cant post the file as it contains confidential information.

Comment: Where is the JSON stored?  If it's already in Azure Blob Storage then Azure SQL Database can import it natively using `OPENROWSET`.